# Is it possible to automate generating a @2x asset by nearest-neighbour scaling when editing a graphical asset @1x?

Tags: automation, sprite, pixel, scaling

Say I have a PNG image file called image.png that I edit pixel by pixel that is 16 pixels wide by 16 pixels tall (16x16). For my usage purposes, I need it to eventually be 3 times in size (i.e. 48 x 48) scaled using the nearest-neighbour scaling algorithm (all hard edges; no blurriness). Currently, I do this manually and export two versions of the same asset, image.png (original) and image@3x.png (48 x 48), every time I make changes, which is somewhat of a hassle. Is there a way to automate my system to generate image@3x.png every time I save changes to image.png? (I am on a Mac).

Comment: You should research some tools ans see what options you have and if there any tools that you can use via a script or command line and try it manually. I think you should also ask this on http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh thanks! I didn't know there was one for graphic design.